Creating a function to calculate number of days in any given month (including leap years)
This question is from a python institute question titled 'How many days: writing and using your own functions'
The goal is to write a function that returns number of days in any given month of a year (leap or otherwise).
def is_leap_year(year):
    if year % 4 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def days_in_month(year, month):
    month_day = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
    if month > 12 or month < 1:
        return None , "Please choose a number between and including 1 and 12"
        if is_leap_year(False):
            return month_day[month - 1]
        if is_leap_year(True) and month == 2:
            month_day[1] == 29
        return month_day[month - 1] 

print(is_leap_year(2024))
print(days_in_month(2024,2))

The above produces:
True
None

2024 is a leap year and therefore returns True - but it does not return 29 days of February. I have played around the the indentation and it produces also True, 28 (still not 29).
Apologies if this is a simple question I am new to python.

Your indentation is off, but maybe that's just here. You want to pass the year to is_leap_year(), not true or false. Your is_leap_year() is too simplistic (but should work for 2024, of course).

Please note, there is more to a leap year than simply being divisible by four.

The main problem is the leap year check:
if is_leap_year(False):

Here, you pass False as argument to the function is_leap_year, which expects the argument to be year. A boolean is a subclass of integer, so is_leap_year(False) evaluates the same as is_leap_year(0) and is_leap_year(True) is is_leap_year(1).
So, is_leap_year(False) is actually True while is_leap_year(True) is False.
Instead you want to check the value of is_leap_year(year). With fixed indentation and a few other changes:
def days_in_month(year, month):
    month_day = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
    if month > 12 or month < 1:
        raise ValueError("Please choose a number between and including 1 and 12")
    if is_leap_year(year) and month == 2:
        return 29
    return month_day[month - 1] 

P.S. As others correctly note, this algorithm for leap year checking may not be accurate but that would depend on the range of input that needs to be supported.

As I said I am new to python so I appreciate the help!
So, in this case, if I have it write just having:
if is_leap_year(year):
this is 'if leap year function is true' (in plain english)? Does this apply universally? Or is it just when I create a function which returns True or False?

Sorry, another question. I understand return 29 is easier and simpler, but what if I wanted it so that month_day [1] changes to 29 and THEN return 29. Would I just do something like month_day[1] ==  29 and then return month_day[1]

The syntax is if {expr}, which is short for if {expr} is True - where {expr} is either a boolean, an expression that evaluates to a boolean,  or something that is boolean like (i.e. an integer that can be treated as True/False)

@IdraqSiddiqui to your first question, yes, I think you got that right. For values other than True and False, they can all be evaluated in this context as "truthy" or "falsy", for example empty lists or empty strings evaluate to False, etc. To your second question, yes, except you use = for assignment rather than ==. But since month_day is a local variable, it doesn't change anything that you change it right before returning from the function, hence my optimization.

y == year
m == month

--------------------------------------------------

maxday_yearmonth = lambda y, m: ((m//8 ^ m | 30) 
    - (m == 2)*(2 - ((not y&3)&bool(y%25) | (not y&15))))

maxday_yearmonth(1965,2)   28
maxday_yearmonth(1964,2)   29

-------------------------------------------------------

maxday_year = lambda y: (((not y&3)&bool(y%25) | (not y&15)) 
    + 365)

maxday_year(1965)  365
maxday_year(1964)  366

------------------------------------------------------

leap_year = lambda y: bool((not y&3)&bool(y%25) | (not y&15))

leap_year(1965)  False
leap_year(1964)  True



Nice compact solution, but it could really use some explanation!

Darf ich es in deutscher Sprache? Ich kann kein english.

Tut mir leid, aber nein, allein Englisch geht hier. https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions
